External BitLocker changed my password authentication to a passphrase authentication
After upgrade to ubuntu 24.04.1. My backup (WDBKJOOO40×××-OA external BitLocker) changed my password authentication to a passphrase  authentication. I know my password but do not know the passphrase. Is there any way Ican resolve this issue without reformatting and losing all my work?

You may need to use your Bitlocker recovery key as the passphrase. A similar question was asked here.
What is the passphrase for opening a BitLocker disk on Ubuntu?
